# How many socket connections can handle Play Framework (Netty)?

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm developing SPA application with play framework in the Back end(v2.5).

As is known , Play (or Netty) can handle many connections due to its async IO.

For each client I want to open socket connection.

**1. How many concurrent socket connections can handle Play framework?**

**2. How will huge amount of open sockets connection affect to overall requests /seconds capability?**